# BackgroundWorker and ReportProgress freezing the UI

Tags: backgroundworker

I am using BackgroundWorker to load large files.  Depending on the file selected it can have only 4000 rows or 400,000 rows.  The number of columns vary also.

I would like to add the rows in batches progressively but quickly.  I have varied the number of rows that consistute a batch. My problem is that the first batch of rows are added to the FlexGrid fine.  If the file is large enough to need an second batch to add, the grid's scrollbars jigger and the screen freezes.

I call the RunWorderAsync method within the button click method to select a file.  I also assign the FlexGrid to the data table as its data source.

The code is as follows:

```
                //bind the grid to the empty table
                c1FlexGrid1.DataSource = dt;

                // go load the data
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(lengthOfFile);
```

The FlexGrid is from ComponentOne and is used for WinForms.

The DoWorker code is as follows:

```
// create rows for data table
    using (StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(filePathAndName))
        while ((lineOfData = streamRead.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            rowCount++;
            sizeOfLine += lineOfData.Length;
            //create a new row in the data table
            var row = dt.NewRow();
            arrayOfData = lineOfData.Split(',');

            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                row[j] = arrayOfData[j];
            }
            newRowData.Add(row);

            percentComplete += 10;
            // inform progress at every 10 percent
            currentPercentComplete = ((double)sizeOfLine / sizeOfFile) * 100;
            if(((int)currentPercentComplete > percentComplete) && (percentComplete < 100))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting UI thread - row count {0}, percent complete {1}, current percent {2}", rowCount, percentComplete, currentPercentComplete);
                percentComplete += 10;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percentComplete);

                // simulate lengthy operation
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

        }//end while loop

    }//end of using 

}
```

The ProgressChanged method is as follows:

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        dt.BeginLoadData();
        for (int i = 0; i < newRowData.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(newRowData[i]);
        }
        dt.EndLoadData();

//        Console.WriteLine("In UI thread ProgressChanged - end load -rows added - {0}", newRowData.Count);

        // done with this batch
        newRowData.Clear();

        // update UI
        this.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any code that updates the UI--which means I'd be guessing at what could be making your UI sluggish.